# GridDB Error (TXN_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT) - Client Request Execution Failure due to Transaction Timeout

Tags: java, nosql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I am currently encountering a persistent issue while working with GridDB, and I am reaching out for assistance in resolving it.

Error Details:
Error Code: 10014
Error Message: TXN_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT
Description: Execution of client request failed.
This error occurs during the execution of a client request in my GridDB setup. The error message indicates that the problem may be related to a transaction timeout. I am using a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

I've attempted to address the issue by setting a longer client "transaction timeout" time. Here is an example of how I've configured it in my code:

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("transactionTimeout", "60");
GridStoreFactory.getInstance().setProperty(prop);
GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getGridStore(prop);
Despite implementing this solution, the problem persists. I would appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to resolve this GridDB error. Is there anything specific I should check or adjust in my configuration to effectively extend the transaction timeout?
```

Thank you for your time and assistance!